SvelteKit wait for Firebase onAuthStateChanged before load function
I'm working with SvelteKit and Firebase to build a website. There's a document in my Firestore that only logged in users can accces, I already set a rule for that. The problem that I'm facing is that the load function which fetchs data from the database is sending back a permission denied error as if the user is not logged in. The load function seems to run before the auth state if changed.
I tried using a simple store that stores the authenticated user to check if the user is signed in, but unfortunately the getDoc function can't be awaited
// $lib/stores/authStore.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { auth } from '$lib/firebase';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
export function authStore(auth) {
    let unsubscribe;

    const { subscribe } = writable(auth.currentUser, (set) => {
        unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            set(user);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe;
    });

    return {
    subscribe
    };
}

// +page.server.js
import { authStore } from '$lib/stores/authStore.js';
import { doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

export async function load() {
    let protectedDoc;
    authStore.subscribe((user) => {
        if (user) {
            const docRef = doc(db, 'myCollection/myDoc')
        await getDoc(docRef).then((snapshot) => {
                protectedDoc = snapshot.data();
            });
            return { protectedDoc }
        };
    })
}

I tried something similar to a few discussions, but had no success
SvelteKit async function load not working or Firebase onAuthStateChanged cannot be made blocking
Firebase split second authentication confirmation is messing with Sveltekit pages due to Firestore rules
Sveltekit: Wait for resolve in +layout.ts before load() in +page.ts
How should I write this load function in order to the read the firebase document only after user auth state is not null?

Using auth.currentUser on the client side is easy, because each user will have their own instance of this, and that way be logged in to different accounts (their own). Using auth.currentUser on the server is on the other side trickier, since the server will receive HTTP requests from different users that are logged in on different accounts, so if you want to use Firebase Authentication on the server, you need to handle this somehow. Do you currently do that?
